# Oracle - Identifying Dominant Records

Tags: string, oracle, comparison

I have a table that contains two `STRING` values (all single words) along with a corresponding `COUNT` for each occurrence of the `STRING`, e.g;

```
ID  STR_1       COUNT_1   STR_2     COUNT_2
1   ORANGES     2         APPLES    10
2   APPLES      10        ORANGES   2
3   ORANGES     2         BANANAS   1
4   BANANAS     1         APPLES    10
5   BANANAS     1         ORANGES   2
```

***N.B.*** `STR_1` is considered the ‘master’ value. Also, the `COUNT` for each individual `STRING` value will be consistent between `STR_1` And `STR_2` and between rows (e.g. `ORANGES` will always have a `COUNT` of `2`)

What I’m trying to achieve is to remove records whereby an ‘enantiomer’ exists, for example; in the above data, `ID 2` would be considered an ‘enantiomer’ of `ID 1` (`ID 1.STR_1 = ID.2 STR_2` and `ID 1.STR_2 = ID.2 STR_1`), however, `ID 2` would be considered the dominant record with `ID 1` being discarded (because the `COUNT` for `APPLES` is greater than the `COUNT` for `ORANGES`) – therefore the desired output would be;

```
ID  STR_1       COUNT_1   STR_2     COUNT_2
2   APPLES      10        ORANGES   2
3   ORANGES     2         BANANAS   1
4   BANANAS     1         APPLES    10
```

**IF** a scenario exists whereby the `COUNT` values between different `STRINGS` match, the longest `STRING` would be considered the dominant record and retained e.g.;

```
ID  STR_1       COUNT_1   STR_2     COUNT_2
1   ORANGES     10        APPLES    10
2   APPLES      10        ORANGES   10
3   ORANGES     10        BANANAS   1
4   BANANAS     1         APPLES    10
5   BANANAS     1         ORANGES   10
```

With the desired output being;

```
ID  STR_1       COUNT_1   STR_2     COUNT_2
1   ORANGES     10        APPLES    10
3   ORANGES     10        BANANAS   1
4   BANANAS     1         APPLES    10
```

Test Data;

```
WITH
  TEST_DATA AS
  (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'ORANGES' STR_1, 2 COUNT_1, 'APPLES' STR_2, 10 COUNT_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 ID, 'APPLES' STR_1, 10 COUNT_1, 'ORANGES' STR_2, 2 COUNT_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 3 ID, 'ORANGES' STR_1, 2 COUNT_1, 'BANANAS' STR_2, 1 COUNT_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 4 ID, 'BANANAS' STR_1, 1 COUNT_1, 'APPLES' STR_2, 10 COUNT_2 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 5 ID, 'BANANAS' STR_1, 1 COUNT_1, 'ORANGES' STR_2, 2 COUNT_2 FROM DUAL
  )
```

Any help finding a solution to the above would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anti join (`not exists` operator):

```
select * 
from test_data t
where not exists (
   select 1 from test_data t1
   where t.str_1 = t1.str_2
    and  t.str_2 = t1.str_1
    and ( 
       t.count_1 < t1.count_1
       or
       t.count_1 = t1.count_1
       and 
       length( t.str_1 ) < length( t1.str_1 )
    )
)
order by id
```

In a case when for a given pair of rows both counts and lengths are equal, then the query picks both rows.

Comment: Many thanks, Krokodilko - this works a treat! Much appreciated.